# How do I check if a generic view class actually implements init(frame:)?

Tags: ios, swift, generics

Let's say I have a custom UIView subclass with a designated initializer:

```swift
class MyView: UIView {

    init(custom: String) {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```

As expected I *cannot* call `MyView(frame: .zero)` as it's not [automatically inherited](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html#ID222) from `UIView`.

Then suppose I have a view builder class:

```
class Builder<V: UIView> {
    func build() -> V? {
        // Check if can call init(frame:) or not
        if V.instancesRespond(to: #selector(V.init(frame:))) {
            return V.init(frame: .zero) // <-- Crash here, because the check doesn't work
        } else { 
            return nil 
        }
    }
}
```

Here I checked first if the custom view `V` has `init(frame:)` or not, if yes, then call it.

However, it doesn't work, `Builder<MyView>().build()` will crash with:

> Fatal error: Use of unimplemented initializer 'init(frame:)' for class '__lldb_expr_14.MyView'

`V.instancesRespond(to: #selector(V.init(frame:)))` always returns `true`, making this check useless. (Or did I use it incorrectly?)

**Question: How do I check if generic view class `V` actually responds to `init(frame:)`?**

---

**Updated 1:**
I also tried `V.responds(to: #selector(V.init(frame:)))` as @kamaldeep and @Pranav have pointed out. However, it always returns `false` no matter I override init(frame:) on `MyView` or not.

**Updated 2: What I'm trying to do:**

To be more clear, I'm building a [framework](https://github.com/aunnnn/ViewElements) that automatically initializes `UIView` from this enum:

```
enum ViewBuildMethod {
    case nib
    case nibName(String)
    case frame(CGRect)
    case custom(() -> UIView)
}
```

and that view to be used with the framework must adopt this protocol and specify how to build:

```
protocol SomeViewProtocol where Self: UIView {

    // ... other funcs

    static func buildMethod() -> ViewBuildMethod
}
```

The issue is that I want the `override init(frame:)` to be **optional** and allows a custom designated initializer (like in `MyView`). Then, emit `fatalError` with an error message when the `init(frame:)` is used (indirectly) on a view that hasn't overridden it yet. This indicates an illegal use of the framework (e.g., `MyView`'s `buildMethod` returns `.frame(.zero)`), that can't be checked in compile time:

```swift
class MyView: UIView, SomeViewProtocol {

    init(custom: String) {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    // ILLEGAL!!
    static func buildMethod() -> ViewBulidMethod {
        return .frame(.zero) // <-- Illegal, the framework will call V.init(frame: .zero) eventually
    }

    // LEGAL
    // static func buildMethod() -> ViewBuildMethod {
    //     return .custom({ () -> UIView in
    //         return MyView(custom: "hello")
    //     })
    // }
}
```

The error message could be sth like `V.init(frame:) is called indirectly but V doesn't override this designated initializer. Please override init(frame:) to fix this issue`. 
I can let it crash like above, but it will be more clear if I can add some meaningful message before that happens.

Comment: Why haven't you used `respondsToSelector`? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/1418956-nsobject/1418583-respondstoselector?language=objc

Comment: @kamaldeepsinghbhatia Thanks for pointing this out, I've also tried `responds(to:)` but it always returns `false` no matter I override `init(frame:)` or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since Swift doesn't automatically inherit from `UIView` it will not be possible to check if your your class implement `init(frame:)` constructor.

I suppose `instancesRespond(to:)` return `true`, because it's checking if your class conform to this message with Message dispatching. However Swift uses Table dispatching for method declared in classes. So this checking will work with Objective-C but not with Swift

So, to achieve what you want, you can use `protocol`

create protocol `Buildable` which will have `init(frame: CGRect)` method

```
protocol Buildable {
    init(frame: CGRect)
}
```

conform your class to this protocol

```
class MyView: UIView, Buildable {...}
```

now `init(frame:)` method will be required for your class. Change generic type of you `Builder` class to `Buildable`

Now your class could be like this

```
class Builder<V: Buildable>  {
    func build() -> V? {
        return V(frame: .zero)
    }
}
```

and now when you will be able to build your view `Builder<MyView>().build()`, and if you class will be not confirm to `Buildable` protocol you will get `compile-time` error:

```
class SecondView: UIView {
    init(custom: String) {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}

Builder<SecondView>().build()
```

will throw compile-time error:

```
error: type 'SecondView' does not conform to protocol 'Buildable'
Builder<SecondView>().build()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So it's impossible to check if the implementation exists right?

Comment: Yes, it's seems to be impossible to check if `init(frame:)` is implemented

Answer (score 1):

it looks like one of many limitations in Swift generics. If this is really needed, you can try to make all the swift objects objc compatible, then you can utilize objc runtime to figure this out, but I personally don't believe this is worth the effort. I'd rather rewrite the code to approach in a different, yet clean, way.

Answer (score 1):

Oddly enough, `init(frame:)` gets synthesized by the compiler, the following code proving it:

```
var methodCount: UInt32 = 0
let methods = class_copyMethodList(MyView.self, &methodCount)!      
for i in 0..<methodCount {
    let method = method_getName(methods[Int(i)])
    print(method, method_getImplementation(methods[Int(i)]))
}
let method = class_getMethodImplementation(UIView.self,  #selector(UIView.init(frame:)))!
print("UIView's init(frame:)",method_getImplementation(method))
```

The output of the above code is

```
initWithCoder: 0x00000001054125b0
initWithFrame: 0x0000000105412790
UIView's init(frame:) 0xffee1be8ffffee20
```

Seems that the so-called required initializer `init(frame:)` gets automatically syntehsized by the compiler into the runtime error you reach into, meaning that there's no way do detect if `init(frame:)` is implemented or not in a `UIView` subclass.

Others have suggested protocol-based implementations, which are clearer and more robust solutions, as they come with compile-time guarantees. I'd recommend going with those solutions.